# Visual Studio Installer Projects con PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, windows-forms, postgresql

Estoy iniciando un proyecto Windows Form C #, una aplicación comercial que el usuario baja, instala y utiliza, sin complicaciones. ¿Es posible configurar Visual Studio Installer Projects para instalar junto PostgreSQL sin que el usuario se dé cuenta? Una instalacion silenciosa.

Comment: a que te referis con una base integrada. dentro del ejecutable?

Comment: ¡Sí, eso mismo! Pensé en SQLite pero para una aplicación comercial, como una tienda creo que no sería una buena solución.

Comment: siguen existiendo? creo que ninguna va integrada al soft. Todos los archivos van por separado. Hace años que no escucho algo asi, pero puedo estar equivocandome. Por lo menos nunca vi ninguna que se pegue a c#

Comment: Sqllite va en un archivo separado...

Comment: De hecho, he dicho equivocado, necesito que vaya junto al mismo instalador.

Comment: entonces por favor modifica tu pregunta usando [edit] . y puedes mandar cualquier base que se te ocurra y te sienta bien en ese caso. no hay una respuesta correcta para esta pregunta, y se considera muy amplia, salvo que pongas mas requerimientos que hagan que exista una respuesta correcta.

Comment: Ok, voy a editar

Comment: @gbianchi listo! Creo que la pregunta es muy específica y dentro de las normas del sitio. ¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Bastante mejor. Pero solo aclara que es sin que se de cuenta. Lo dices como una instalacion silenciosa?

Comment: Quizas te pueda servir utilizar Acess

Comment: Para eso (creo) deberías crear tu el instalador de postgre (que es cuando le asignas el poder realizar una instalación "silenciosa")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para instalar `PostgreSQL` desde tu instalador solo tienes que automatizar dicho proceso. Casi cualquier instalador puede ser automatizado desde una linea de comando para que le pongas los parámetros que el usuario seleccionaría durante el proceso de instalación y para que se instale en modo silent.

Si quieres saber las opciones disponibles puedes mirar aquí: [Silent installation of a MSI package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package):